# Xcode UITests html report generator

Tags: xcode, ui-automation

I am using **Xcode UITests** and **xcpreatty** for generating html reports.
With this command in terminal:

```
xcodebuild -workspace waave.xcworkspace -scheme waave -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 5,OS=9.3' test | xcpretty --report html --output Reports/reportIPhone5.htm
```

I am getting report like this:

[image]

I would like to add additional comments to each test and see it in html report.

Is there any tool that can provide me that?

Comment: There's https://github.com/TitouanVanBelle/XCUITestHTMLReport that provide a bit more features that xcpretty when it comes to UI Tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using XCTestHTMLReport
https://github.com/TitouanVanBelle/XCTestHTMLReport